# Does continuity imply weak differentiability?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have recently been reading about weak derivatives. I have found few examples of only weakly differentiable functions and they were all continuous. Is there an example of a continuous function which is not weakly differentiable or is this a theorem that continuous functions are weakly differentiable ?

I will appreciate any counterexamples or references.

Comment: [Cantor's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: See ACL characterization of Sobolev functions.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli the cantor function is differentiable with derivative 0 a.e so doesn't that imply it is also weakly derivative?

Comment: Only almost-everywhere constant functions have weak derivative zero. So this proves the exact contrary. Remember that the weak derivative must satisfy the integral relation $$\langle f,\phi'\rangle=-\langle f',\phi\rangle $$ for all $\phi\in C_0^\infty (0,1) $